# How do I use row_number and case statement for this SQL exercise?

Tags: sql

I'm doing an sql exercise and am stuck.  If I have database schema as in Computer Firm http://sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1 and the problem is described as:

> Renumber the unique pairs {maker, type} from Product table, having ordered them as follows:
>    - A name of the manufacturer (maker) in ascending;
>    - Type of a product (type) in the order: PC, Laptop, Printer.
>   If a manufacturer produces more than one type of product, deduce its name only in the first row;
>   other rows for THIS manufacturer should contain an empty string ('').

My query:

```
select 
    row_number() over (ORDER BY 
        maker ASC, 
        CASE type when 'PC' THEN 1 WHEN 'Laptop' THEN 2 WHEN 'Printer' THEN 3 END
    ) num, 
    maker, type 
from product 
order by maker, CASE type when 'PC' THEN 1 WHEN 'Laptop' THEN 2 WHEN 'Printer' THEN 3 END
```

My (incorrect) answer:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| num | maker |  type   |
+-----+-------+---------+
|   1 | A     | PC      |
|  10 | C     | Laptop  |
|  11 | D     | Printer |
|  12 | D     | Printer |
|  13 | E     | PC      |
|  14 | E     | PC      |
|  15 | E     | PC      |
|  16 | E     | Printer |
|   2 | A     | PC      |
|   3 | A     | Laptop  |
|   4 | A     | Laptop  |
|   5 | A     | Printer |
|   6 | A     | Printer |
|   7 | A     | Printer |
|   8 | B     | PC      |
|   9 | B     | Laptop  |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

The correct answer looks like:

```
+-----+-------+---------+
| num | maker |  type   |
+-----+-------+---------+
|   1 | A     | PC      |
|   2 |       | Laptop  |
|   3 |       | Printer |
|   4 | B     | PC      |
|   5 |       | Laptop  |
|   6 | C     | Laptop  |
|   7 | D     | Printer |
|   8 | E     | PC      |
|   9 |       | Printer |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

EDIT

This is what the site says it uses in terms of SQL support: `Now we use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on the rating stages, and MySQL 5.5.11, PostgreSQL 9.0, and Oracle Database 11g on the learn stage in addition.`.  This question comes from the learning stage.

Comment: You appear to have more rows than the correct answer, why is that?

Comment: You tagged `mysql` -- did you mean `sql server` or another database that supports analytic functions?

Comment: Thanks, I removed the tag.  This is what the site says it uses in terms of SQL support: `Now we use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on the rating stages, and MySQL 5.5.11, PostgreSQL 9.0, and Oracle Database 11g on the learn stage in addition. `.  This question comes from the learning stage.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to build a query for this:

```
Select 
row_number() OVER(
ORDER BY maker,
CASE    WHEN type = 'PC' THEN '1'
        WHEN type = 'Laptop' THEN '2'
        WHEN type = 'Printer' THEN '3'
        ELSE type  END ASC) num,
CASE WHEN 
row_number() OVER(
PARTITION BY maker
ORDER BY CASE   WHEN type = 'PC' THEN '1'
                WHEN type = 'Laptop' THEN '2'
                WHEN type = 'Printer' THEN '3'
                ELSE type  END ASC) =1
                THEN maker
                ELSE '' END as maker,
type 
FROM
(select distinct maker,type from product) as p
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query would give the expected output for MySql:

```
select rank, manufacturer, type 
from (
  select @r:=@r+1 AS rank,
  if( @lastmaker = maker, '', maker ) as manufacturer, 
  type, @lastmaker := maker
  from product, (SELECT @r:=0, @lastmaker:='') r
  order by maker, type
) mytable;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d0901/19/0) for example.

Comment: In the window on the exercise site, I get a message: `Must declare the scalar variable "@r".` - how do I do this in that statement?

Comment: Which exercise site are you referring to?